# Combining Chemicals

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I wanted to ask purely from a theoretical point of view what would happen if you were to combine Lanthanum Uranium and Radium together? I chose it as my project since it spells my name purely for comical reasons but since i can't find it anywhere i'm genuinely curious.

Comment: From a purely theoretical point of view, they would form a trimer consisting out of La, U and Ra. I'm pretty sure there is a minimum somewhere on the potential energy surface. Maybe it exists in space somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

They will perhaps form an alloy. Depends on the atomic radii of the three elements (they need to be similar, you can check on wikipedia).

Or, if the radii are (suitably) dissimilar, you might get some sort of intermetallic phase (like e.g. brass).

However I seriously doubt that anyone has ever investigated the phase diagram of this specific ternary mixture. Radium is just too radioactive for most people to care.

(You might have suspected this, with three metals: There will be no interesting reaction. :-/)

Answer (score -1):

Two radioactive elements made to react????
Doubt the reaction's feasibility based on various factors such as -

1. Thermodynamic point of view (huge amount of energy may be required).
2. Kinetic point of view
3. Most importantly, cost of carrying out such a futile reaction.

Comment: 1+2 are completely unfounded statements.

Comment: How exactly may i know @Karl

Comment: Radioactivity and chemical reactivity have nothing to do with each other. An alloy or intermetallic phase just forms from the melt, or doesn't. Very few reactions require a "huge amounts of energy" to take place, because that usually means the product would not be stable. What gives you the idea that this "reaction" would be kinetically hindered?